# analyzing vmcore taken over raw disk

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash-dumps

I have core dump (vmcore) of a Red Hat Linux machine taken over raw disk partition. The vmcore is generated and i could see that on my serial console output.  i had triggered the core dump proces using `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger` but am not aware how to analyze it.

The option specified in `/etc/kdump.conf` file was `"raw /dev/sda5"`. I had created /dev/sda5 parition using fdisk command before hand and gave as location for dump file. I had also done other things like reserving memory for crash etc.

Googling for this gave some info like the following :-

"The raw disk partition and dedicated file system options allow you to still dump to the local system, but without having to remount your possibly corrupted file system(s),
thereby decreasing the chance a vmcore won't be captured. Assuming/dev/sda5 is left unformatted, kdump.conf can be configured with 'raw/dev/sda5', and the vmcore file will be copied via dd directly onto partition/dev/sda5".

I cannot find `/proc/vmcore` after machine reboots (after taking dump). Can some one provide me any clue/steps how i can analyze that dump? Do i need to do "dd" or "mknod" or something similar (got some unclear hints about it on google).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I happened to see your question. Don't know if you got your answer already.. Anyways..

vmcore will be copied to /var/crash/ or the location defined in the  path parameter, if any..

As save_raw function is defined.

```
function save_raw()
{
        local raw_part=$(awk '$1 ~ /^raw$/ { print $2; }' $KDUMP_CONFIG_FILE)
        local kdump_dir
        if [ "$raw_part" ]; then
                [ -b "$raw_part" ] || {
                        echo "raw partition $raw_part not found"
                        return 1
                }
                kdump_dir=`grep ^path $KDUMP_CONFIG_FILE | cut -d' '  -f2-`
                if [ -z "${kdump_dir}" ]; then
                        coredir="/var/crash/`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"`"
                else
                        coredir="${kdump_dir}/`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M"`"
                fi
                mkdir -p "$coredir"
                [ -d "$coredir" ] || {
                        echo "failed to create $coredir"
                        return 1
                }
                if makedumpfile -R $coredir/vmcore <$raw_part >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                        # dump found
                        echo "Dump saved to $coredir/vmcore"
                        # wipe makedumpfile header
                        dd if=/dev/zero of=$raw_part bs=1b count=1 2>/dev/null
                else
                        rm -rf "$coredir"
                fi
        fi
        return 0
}
```

The function is called when the kdump is starting up after reboot.

```
function start()
{
        save_raw
```